# Can I pass char* to const char* in C?

Tags: c, char, constants

I am implementing a function that converts string into double in C. The function is not destructive, i.e. I do not modify the string passed and I just read it in the function. I want to pass char*, const char*, and also string literal to the function.

Is the following function appropriate for this purpose? I think the question comes down to whether passing char* to const char* is defined and allowed in C.

```
double str2double( const char* input);
```

Thank you. (I've found some similar question title, but their answers are vague for me, and I am asking here.)

Comment: Yes you can do that. Did you try?

Comment: Trick: either you read the standard (which you need to check every time, because the complex exceptions), or you should test, adding all warnings to compiler.

Comment: Non-const to const conversion is valid and good. Const to non-const is a red flag.

Comment: @Jabberwocky wrong duplicate. That is a C program compiled with C++ compiler

Comment: @Jabberwocky ah it isn't, I am writing an answer there too :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, `char *input` can be *assigned* to a variable of type `const char *`, with an implicit type conversion, and C arguments work *as if by assignment*. The rule is this in [C11 6.5.16.1.1](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.16.1):

> 6.5.16.1 Simple assignment
>
> **Constraints**
>
> 1. One of the following shall hold:
>
> [...]
>
> - the left operand has atomic, qualified, or unqualified pointer type, and (considering the type the left operand would have after lvalue conversion) both operands are pointers to qualified or unqualified versions of compatible types, and the type pointed to by the left has all the qualifiers of the type pointed to by the right;
>
> [...]

In doing

```
const char *cinput;
cinput = input;
```

the left operand `cinput` has *unqualified pointer type* (the pointer type *itself* is not `const`-qualified); and so does the right operand.

The left operand is a pointer **to** a **const-qualified** type (`const char`), and *the type pointed to by* right operand does not have any qualifiers. The type pointed to by the left has therefore **all** qualifiers of the type *pointed to by* the right **and** additional `const` qualifier, hence the assignment is valid.

And in calling a function

```
double str2double(const char* input);

[...]

char *foo = ...
str2double(foo);
```

the behaviour is as if the value of `foo` was assigned to the `input` *parameter* by a simple assignment.

A string literal in C is of type an array of *unqualified char*, which decays to `char *`, i.e. if it were not OK to pass `char *` into such a function, you could not use `double str2double( const char* input);` passing a *string literal* as the argument.

Comment: Thank you for your precise answer, referring to standard. @John 's answer is also very useful, practical and more intuitive.

Comment: @toshi-san an intuitive answer can also be vague, imprecise or even wrong. For example were the variable of type `char **`, you could not assign it to `const char **`, even though it does look like it would be OK...

Comment: Yes, that's why I chose your answer as the best one. Thanks for the additional comment. `char**` cannot be assigned to `const char*` b/c `char*` and `const char*` do not seem to be compatible. I think I need to read standards more about this kind of thing.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is allowed. Using `const` in this case is good practice. By adding it to the function arguments you promise not to modify the data located at `input`.

Comment: You could improve this answer by adding that `const` simply means you promise not to modify the data. It covers all the OP’s use cases.